# Xamarin.Mac Editing the NSTableView to save new values in place of the older information

Tags: c#, xamarin, cocoa, nstableview, xamarin.mac

I was looking into creating an NSTable view that can edit and save the data that is retrieved. For clarity, I basically sending out a Json file into this table I want to use this table as the interface for a user to modify the contents that are later saved and sent out in another JSON object to be serialized later. The documentation on tableviews doesn't specify where the edited date goes or how it's saved. I would appreciate any help on the subject.

Here is the TableController:

```
public partial class LightTableViewController : NSViewController
    {
        public LightTableViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;
                // Update the view, if already loaded.
            }
        }

        
        public override void AwakeFromNib()
        {
            base.AwakeFromNib();

            // Create the Light Table Data Source and populate it
            var DataSource = new LightTableDataSource();


            DataExchange.Deserialize().ForEach(i => DataSource.LightingDevices.Add(i));
            //DataSource.LightingDevices.Add(new LightingDevice("Xamarin.Mac", "Allows you to develop Mac native Applications in C#"));

            // Populate the Product Table
            LightTable.DataSource = DataSource;
            LightTable.Delegate = new LightTableDelegate(DataSource);

        }
    }
```

Here is the Table Delegate:

```
 public override NSView GetViewForItem(NSTableView tableView, NSTableColumn tableColumn, nint row)
        {
            // This pattern allows you reuse existing views when they are no-longer in use.
            // If the returned view is null, you instance up a new view
            // If a non-null view is returned, you modify it enough to reflect the new data
            NSTextField view = (NSTextField)tableView.MakeView(CellIdentifier, this);
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = new NSTextField();
                view.Identifier = CellIdentifier;
                view.BackgroundColor = NSColor.Clear;
                view.Bordered = false;
                view.Selectable = true;
                view.Editable = true;

                view.EditingEnded += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    // Take action based on type
                    switch (view.Identifier)
                    {
                        case "Channel":
                            DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)view.Tag].channel = view.StringValue;
                            break;
                        case "Position":
                            DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)view.Tag].position = view.StringValue;
                            break;
                    }
                };
            }

            // Setup view based on the column selected
            switch (tableColumn.Title)
            {
                case "Channel":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].channel;
                    break;

                case "Instrument Type":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].instrumentType;
                    break;

                case "Position":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].position;
                    break;

                case "Unit #":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].userField2; //change to unit# when the script can export it
                    break;

                case "Wattage":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].wattage;
                    break;

                case "Patch":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].patch;
                    break;

                case "DMX Footprint":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].dmxFootprint;
                    break;

                case "Color":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].color;
                    break;

                case "Class":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].@class;
                    break;

                case "Layer":
                    view.StringValue = DataSource.LightingDevices[(int)row].layer;
                    break;
            }

            return view;
        }
```

And the Data Source class is functionally the same as the examples in the Table Views example.

Also if anyone suggests using Key-Value data binding I have tried that and there are issues with the JSON parser when extending the NSObject class to the relevant data model. Hence why I am using a simple table.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out one way of doing this. And that was to first change the switch case in the `switch (view.Identifier)` to  `switch (tableColumn.Title)` so it sees the columns that need to be edited. After that change out the `DataSource.*YourList<T>*[(int)view.Tag]` in each switch case with a method to where the data in question is stored. I used static types since I'm mainly flinging around objects but use what best suits you. After that, I serialize the data to a JSON object, but again you do you.

All in all it should look like this:

```
                view.EditingEnded += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    // Take action based on type
                    switch (tableColumn.Title)
                    {
                        case "Column Header Name":
                            MyClass.StaticMethodThatReturnsList<T>()[(int)view.Tag].fieldWithinTheObjectType<T> = view.StringValue;
                            MyOtherClass.Serialize(); // serialize to json file
                            break;

//repeat
```

If anyone knows a better way I would love to hear it. If not I hope this helps!